# How can I print/log entire body contents of MultiPartEntity that is being used by HTTPRequest?

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest, multipartentity

I want to verify what exactly is in HTTP request i.e Parameters and Headers. The code, which I am debugging uses MultiPartEntity to setEntity before making executing HTTP Request.

```
response = executePost(multipartEntity);
statusCode = response.statusCode;
```

I am not getting the expected response from the server hence want to verify what is the exact thing (url + parameters) that is being send to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: android has no MultiPartEntity support

Comment: Project uses Apache mime4j library. No issues whatsover.

Answer (score 7):

Something like the following will do the trick:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
multipartEntity.writeTo(bytes);
String content = bytes.toString();
```

As suhas_sm mentioned the getContent() method exists but is not implemented.

Comment: This was a MUCH more elegant answer than my previous attempts with InputStream, BufferedReader and StringBuilder, and it works for all Entity types. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved by this

```
MultipartEntity reqEntityB = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream out = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream(
                (int) reqEntityB.getContentLength());
        reqEntityB.writeTo(out);
        String entityContentAsString = new String(out.toByteArray());
        Log.e("multipartEntitty:", "" + entityContentAsString);
```